# Why ELSE statement is executed before IF statement?

Tags: python, json, if-statement

when I try to check if a value is on my JSON list, the else statement is being executed before my IF statement.

so If I write the name: MartinDufour the program will tell me NO and then tell me YES. Which is not normal..(See the short program below to understand)

```
import json

with open("user.json") as k:
    data = json.load(k)


def addlb():
    for i in data["person"]:
        if i["Name"] == name:
            print("Yes")
            break
        else:
            print("No")



print("Write the Name:")
name = input()

addlb()
```

the user.json

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "Name": "Peter",
      "Number": "5143324232"
    },
    {
      "Name": "MartinDufour",
      "Number": "5147745840"
    },
    {
      "Name": "OlivierDeschamps",
      "Number": "5145544029"
    },
    {
      "Name": "DenisCodere",
      "Number": "5143324242"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You don't break in the `else` so the loop goes around again.

Comment: you are looping through all the json items and for each one that doesn't match you are printing "no". So it makes sense that first you get all the "no"s preceding the match.

Comment: Ok well I understand now.. thank you,, But do you guys know the code to look in the entire json list before the else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
import json

with open("user.json") as k:
    data = json.load(k)


def addlb():
    found_name=False
    for i in data["person"]:
        if i["Name"] == name:
            found_name=True
            break
    if found_name:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")




print("Write the Name:")
name = input()

addlb()
```

What you are doing here is noting if you found the name using the `found_name` variable. If you never find it, then `found_name` will remain false. If it ever finds it, then it gets set to true.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the builtin function `any`, which returns True if any of the conditions return True otherwise it returns False.

```
import json

with open("user.json") as k:
    data = json.load(k)

def addlb(name):

    found = any(n['Name'] == name for n in data['person'])
    print('Yes' if found else 'No')   


print("Write the Name:")
name = input()

addlb(name)
```

Comment: Interesting, ty